# Bundled binary files with Pyinstaller (--onefile) are present but still not found at runtime?

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

Good day,

While trying to make a standalone (--onefile) exe with Pyinstaller, I ran into a strange error. The execution does not find two .dll even though they were properly packed into the exe and are properly placed into a `temp/_MEIPASSxxxxx` folder at runtime, as the screenshots below show. This does not happen on the development computer.

[image]

.
[image]

I added my data (icon & readme) in this folder too thanks to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674790/bundling-data-files-with-pyinstaller-onefile) and the program has no problem with finding them, so the issue is only with binaries and not data apparently. Also there is no problem at all in --onedir mode, only --onefile.

Here is my .spec:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(5000)

added_binaries = [
                 ("python36.dll", "."),
                 ("api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll", ".")
                 ] 

added_data = [
             ("PilotageIcon.png", "."),
             ("PilotageREADME.pdf", ".")
             ]

a = Analysis(['Pilotage.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\local-adm\\Desktop\\Lucas\\Keithley\\2018 07 18'],
             binaries=added_binaries,
             datas=added_data,
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          name='Pilotage',
          debug=True,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True,
          icon='PilotageIcon.ico'
          )
```

I read many other threads here but they do not match my situation as **clearly the files are there**, so I don't understand why the errors. Thank you in advance.

Python version: 3.6.3

Pyinstaller version: 3.3.1

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround, **not a fix**, is to install *Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015*  on the machine. Hopefully that helps someone. [Credit](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1566#issuecomment-146564554).

It's not exactly ideal because it adds more steps to follow for the final user.